# How to read messages from Kafka using Core spark for batch processing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform

Can I read messages from Kafka without Spark Streaming? I mean only with Spark Core library for the batch processing purpose.
If yes can you please show some examples how to do it. I am using HDP 2.4, Kafka 0.9 and Spark 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

There is a class called `KafkaUtils` in spark streaming kafka api.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-8/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.scala

From this class you can use a method `createRDD`, which is basically expecting offsets and it is useful only for non-streaming applications.

**Dependency jar:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, check Kafka Connect, for example you want to read Kafka topic data and populate the data in HDFS, its very simple using Kafka Connect.

http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/
http://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Comment: Thank you shankar do I need to configure anything for kerberos for this api?

Comment: @nilesh1212 : not required, just add the dependency in pom.xml and you can use that class.

Comment: @nilesh1212 : Since you are using Kafka as a input source, why don't you use Spark streaming?

Comment: We will be using spark streaming for near real time use case, this is just a temporary work around.

Comment: Do I need to configure offset for each and every spark batch job to read messages from Kafka?